# Boxes in boxes + text, alignment on the page HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to arrange my text in boxes, two boxes side by side, and each box has a header-type of element at the top-right corner. This is what I have come up so far: does what I want, but looks ugly, because it is slightly out of alignment. What would be a better way to do it? no bootstrapping though.

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#p1 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: Orange;
  font-size: large;
  float: right;
}

#p2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

#dogerbox {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

div+p {
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: Orange;
  font-size: large;
  float: right;
}

#first {
  width: 330px;
  height: 250px;
  background: LightBlue;
  overflow: visible;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#first #headers {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 7%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 65%;
  background: Orange;
  left: 6px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1px;
}

#second {
  width: 330px;
  height: 250px;
  background: LightBlue;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  left: 332px;
  bottom: 252px;
  margin: 1px;
}

#second #headers {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 7%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 65%;
  background: Orange;
  left: 6px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
  <div id="headers"> First box </div>
  It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
  content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions
  have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</div>
<div id="second">
  <div id="headers"> Second box</div>
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32.
</div>
<div>
  It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
  content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions
  have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</div>
```

Comment: css-grid or flexbox would be the modern way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend you to use a css-grid or a flexbox for modern approach. In this case a css-grid is the better approach as it can be controlled in height and width simultaniosly.

For that I wrapped your 2 boxes in another div with the class: `grid-wrapper`.
I changed that box to a grid system by using: `display: grid;`.
To get 2 columns you use: `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);`. If you want 3 columns, you change the 2 into a 3 or any number you like for more.
To seperate the boxes, you can use: `grid-gap`.

One thing I want to make you aware of: You had an invalid HTML use by using the ID `#header` twice. An ID has to be unique. ALWAYS! As such, I changed it into a class.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#first,
#second {
  background: LightBlue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.headers {
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  margin: -8px -8px 0.2em 0.2em;
  background: Orange;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div id="first">
    <div class="headers"> First box </div>
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
    content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various
    versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    <div class="headers"> Second box</div>
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is using **flex**.

And this solution is **responsive mobile devices**, without the use of media queries. Run the snippet and resize the browser window. The blocks will adapt to the size of the window.

Also, never use the `id` attribute multiple times. `id` is a unique attribute. Use `class` for many elements.

And always wrap your content in the **main** parent element.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

p {
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: Orange;
  font-size: large;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.headers {
  background: Orange;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
}

#first,
#second {
  background: LightBlue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="first">
    <div class="headers"> First box </div>
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
    content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions
    have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    <div class="headers"> Second box</div>
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32.
  </div>
</div>
```